# Convert git ssh without protocol to one with protocol

Tags: javascript, regex, url, url-scheme, urlparse

Im looking to convert this ssh url

```
[user@]server:project.git
```

to this ssh url

```
ssh://[user@]server/project.git
```

I have this function below, is this all that would need to convert the string? Any points of failure or optimizations?

```
function getCleanSshUrl (location) {
  let parsedLocation = url.parse(location)
  if (!parsedLocation.protocol) {
    parsedLocation = url.parse(`ssh://${location}`)
    const hasColon = location.match(parsedLocation.hostname + ':')
    if (hasColon) {
      parsedLocation.pathname = parsedLocation.pathname.replace(/^\/:/, '/')
    }
  }
  return url.format(parsedLocation)
}
```

Is it possible to do this all in one regex?

Comment: Ain't you doing a simple replacement `"[user@]server:project.git".replace(/([^:]+):(.*)/, "ssh://$1/$2")`?

Comment: I am looking for a regex that would produce the same output "ssh://[user@]server/project.git" for both of the strings "ssh://[user@]server/project.git" and  "[user@]server:project.git".

Answer (score 3):

I think you are complicating things, use a regex to match unwanted format which in other case will return input string itself:

```js
function getCleanSshUrl (location) {
    return location.replace(/^\s*(\[[^:]+):(.*)/, "ssh://$1/$2");
}

console.log(getCleanSshUrl('[user@]server:project.git'));
console.log(getCleanSshUrl('ssh://[user@]server/project.git'))
```

Comment: so in your second example replace does nothing , it just returns the passed string as nothing matches the regex , i mean this `console.log(getCleanSshUrl('ssh://[user@]server/project.git'))`

Comment: It goes through replacement process but nothing happens. Actually you don't need `||` too. See update.